# MQTT not working in HTTPS server

Tags: websocket, wss, mosquitto

We are facing issue in MQTT connection in HTTPS server. Sometime it is working fine and some time it is getting error like below.

WebSocket connection to 'wss://MYHOST:8083/mqtt' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

## Let me share with you my mosquitto.conf file.

> pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid
> persistence true
> persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
> log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
> include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
> listener 1883
>
> listener 8083 
> protocol websockets
> certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/myhost.crt
> cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt
> keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/myhost.key

## My Mosquitto WebSocket config file:

> host = 'MYHOST';  // hostname or IP address  
> port = 8083;
> topic = 'TOPIC';      // topic to subscribe to
> useTLS = true;
> username = "";
> password = "";
> path = "/mqtt";
> cleansession = true;

Thanks.

Comment: Have you found the solution? I am facing the same issue. I am not able to connect to MQTT broker over https.